# Блоки выровнять по самому высокому

Tags: html, css, wordpress, bootstrap

Есть ли какой то универсальный способ как выровнять блоки по высоте самого высоко блока.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Использую bootstrap, а он с flex не дружит, таблица  тоже не вариант. Делаю тему на wordpress, по этому сразу вопрос может можно как то ограничивать пользователя который выкладывает контент (ограниченный размер картинки, фикс длинна статьи (превью), ограниченная длина заголовка), и правильно ли это?

Comment: почему bootstrap не дружит с flex? Если у вас не получается что то сделать из-за особенностей вашего проекта, то будьте добры приложить воспроизводимый код того что вы хотите поменять.

Answer (score 1):

Блоки выравниваются через display: table и display: table-cell
Смотрите пример. Причем в примере можете заменить vertical-aligh: top на vertical-align: middle. И блоки выровняются посередине по вертикали.

```html
<div style="width: 100%; display: table;">
  <div style="width: 50%; display: table-cell; background: red; vertical-align: top;">
    <p>left header</p>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 50%; display: table-cell; background: yellow;  vertical-align: top;">
    <p>right header</p>
    <p>line1</p>
    <p>line2</p>
    <p>line3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Обрезать часть выводимого контента можно как средствами самого Wordpress:

```
function my_content( $content ){
    // сделать все что угодно здесь с $content, обрезать например
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'my_content');
```

(есть еще фильтры the_excerpt, excerpt_length...)
так и средствами css. Для содержимое "цветных блоков" нужно обернуть еще в один div с таким примерно css:

```
max-height: 3em;
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score -1):

Есть старый [хак](http://htmlbook.ru/content/kolonki-odinakovoy-vysoty) для эмуляции одиноковых колонок при помощи `border` или [вариант](https://www.kobzarev.com/programming/jquery-snippets-equal-column-height/) с использованием javascript/jQuery:

**HTML:**

```
<div style="height:350px;" class="column"></div>
<div class="column"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
var max_height = 0;
$("div.column").each(function(){
   if ($(this).height() > max_height) { max_height = $(this).height(); }
});
$("div.column").height(max_height);
```